# How to add styling to autocomplete predictions in google maps API for android?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, autocomplete

I am using Google Maps API v2 Android for my project in which I am using PlaceAutocomplete Predictions API to fetch the suggestions. My question is how to make the suggestions look more dynamic i.e. as the user types, the letters in the suggestions that matches the input provided should change colour, similar to Google Maps like the following (here the letters 'n', 'e' and 'w' go bold in the suggestions):

[image]

I have read the documentation [one](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompletePrediction#getFullText(/android.text.style.CharacterStyle)) and [two](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically), which says:

> `getFullText(CharacterStyle matchStyle)` returns the full text of a place description. This is a combination of the primary and secondary text. Example: "Eiffel Tower, Avenue Anatole France, Paris, France". In addition, this method lets you highlight the sections of the description that match the search with a style of your choice, using `CharacterStyle`. The CharacterStyle parameter is optional. Set it to null if you don't need any highlighting.

But I couldn't find any further explanation in the documentation on how to implement `CharacterStyle` with `getFullText(CharacterStyle)`, please help. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

// Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
// Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
// styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

return row;

}
```